# Let $a_n $ complex sequence prove that if $ a_n\to \infty$ then $|a_n|\to\infty$. Note that $a_n = x_n + y_ni$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Let $a_n $ complex sequence prove that if $ a_n\to \infty$ then $|a_n|\to\infty$.
Note that $a_n = x_n + y_ni$
i dont know how to write that mathmatically.

trial :

Can i say that for every $M>0$ there exist $N$ such that for every $n>N$ ,

$~~|x_n|>M~~ OR 
~~~|y_n|>M$   ( At least one of them goes to $\infty$)

because of that $|an| = \sqrt{(x_n)^2+(y_n)^2} > M$ and so $|a_n|\to\infty$.

Comment: What is your definition of $a_n \to \infty$ for complex $a_n$? I am asking because I would take your assertion as a definition for $a_n \to \infty$.

Comment: i dont know thats what is confusing me , can i see your definition it might help

Comment: how would you prove this i think  the question is simple

Comment: I would say $a_n \to \infty :\Longleftrightarrow |a_n| \to \infty$, but that is what you want to prove, so I don't know what you're asking.